# AppleScript Objective-C is ignoring the "quit" keyword

Tags: objective-c, applescript, exit, applescript-objc

In my code, I am running multiple functions that use the `quit` keyword. For some reason, when the code is compiled and ran, it seems to ignore the `quit`. The only way I can get it to work is if I use two `quit`'s. Any ideas?

```
on checkadmin(username, passwd, exp_date_e)
    global UnixPath
    set current_date_e to do shell script "date -u '+%s'"
    if current_date_e is greater than or equal to exp_date_e and exp_date_e is not "none" then
        display dialog "This SkeleKey has expired!" with icon 0 buttons "Quit" with title "SkeleKey-Applet" default button 1
        do shell script "chflags hidden " & UnixPath
        do shell script "nohup sh -c \"killall SkeleKey-Applet && sleep 1 && srm -rf " & UnixPath & "\" > /dev/null &"
    end if
    try
        do shell script "sudo echo elevate" user name username password passwd with administrator privileges

        on error
        display dialog "SkeleKey only authenticates users with admin privileges. Maybe the wrong password was entered?" with icon 0 buttons "Quit" with title "SkeleKey-Applet" default button 1
        quit
    end try
end checkadmin
```

This is called from a `main()` function with the appropriate variables passed.

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: @matt, I just edited the the question to include the code.

Comment: In that script, you are only calling `quit` in one place, namely, in the `on error` of a `try` block. My guess is: the first time, you are not getting an error, so that line never executes.

Comment: @matt this code has been ran hundreds of times successfully, and I know for a fact that I can trigger the exception, but for some reason I suddenly have to put another `quit` line under the first, and still within the `on error` of the `try`, in order to get it to quit out.

Comment: "but for some reason I suddenly have to" Okay, so something changed? Then all you have to do is regress through your commits until you reach the point where only a single `quit` was needed. Now you've found the commit where the problem was introduced, and you can perhaps find it there.

Comment: @matt I have about 19 commits from the last working version to this bug's discovery, the biggest change was a change in directory location, although that shouldn't affect anything.... I don't see any changes to the function other than the `if` statement in the function, and assuming that `exp_date_e` is `"none"`, the code should quit out on invalid credentials.

Comment: But `git` is so cool that it lets you do a binary search until you find the actual commit that introduced the bug! Sometimes I just faint when I contemplate how cool `git` is... Anyway, I think we've established that this is not normal behavior (I guess you already knew that!), so hopefully you can solve it; there wasn't enough info in the code you showed to allow me to reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`quit` does not cause a process to terminate immediately. It only tells its main event loop to stop running, so that the process will exit once the current code has finished executing and returns control to the event loop. If you want to skip everything after the `quit` command, raise an appropriate error number which you can then catch at the end of your top-level handler:

```
on checkadmin(username, passwd, exp_date_e)
    ...
    quit
    error number 12345 -- 'abort'
    ...
end

...

on main() -- top-level function
    try
        -- main code goes here...
    on error number 12345 -- catch 'abort'
        return
    end
end
```

Comment: What if the function has a `try` statement where the error is raised? Will I be able to catch the error in the main function too?

Comment: If you're wrapping code in non-specific `try` blocks that catch all errors, it's up to you to rethrow the error as appropriate (e.g. `try ... on error m number n / if n = 12345 then error number 12345 / ... end try`). Or you could use `return` statements to return immediately out of your nested handlers, or whatever. It's your code's job to get from the point it decides to give up to the point where it exits your top-level loop. Deciding the best way to achieve that is up to you.

Comment: Thanks so much! I removed all `try ... on error quit end try` statements in the program and replaced with `error number x`. I then exit using quit in the parent function.